# Laravel - SQL Raw obtener un solo registro

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

Tengo esta consulta `sql` en mi proyecto laravel que hago directamente ya que es bastante compleja y de momento no la he pasado al ORM de laravel (solo pongo una linea de la sql para preservar la privacidad)

```
    $fecha_ayer = Carbon::now()->addDays(-1)->format('Y-m-d');

    $sqlConsultaCoches = "SELECT count(*) as totalCochesDisponibles
            FROM coches a where DATE(a.fecha_creacion) = '$fecha_ayer'";

    $consultaCoches = DB::connection('mysql-external')->select($sqlConsultaCoches);
```

Ahora quiero acceder al valor que me devuelve esta consulta, lo hago de esta manera:

```
$consultaCoches[0]->totalCochesDisponibles
```

Esto funciona, pero mi pregunta es me puedo ahorrar el `"[0]"`, es decir **si solo va a devolver un resultado la sql**.

> ¿como puedo hacerlo para devolver solo ese valor sin pasar por un array?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas modelos y Eloquent para simplificar tu consulta?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar query builder para mejorar tu consulta

```
$ayer = Carbon::now()->subDay()->format('Y-m-d');

$coches = DB::connection('mysql-external')->table('coches')->whereDate('fecha_creacion', $ayer)->count();

dd($coches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar la función `first` que retorna un solo elemento del `array`, y como la función se llama este siempre sera el primero, osea el de la posición 0.

```
$consultaCoches = DB::connection('mysql-external')->select($sqlConsultaCoches)->first();
```

Luego accedes directamente a los valores "ahorrándote" el `[0]`.

```
$consultaCoches->totalCochesDisponibles
```

Comment: Esta opción ya la probé y en la 1º linia donde hace el first, me da este error.     Call to a member function first() on array